# scipy.optimize problems using an integrated function

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, matplotlib, scipy

I've have been trying to fit a Voight profile to a set of data using the scipy package in python. Specifically, the import scipy.optimize package. I have an old code that does this fine using the wolfz function, however I can't use the wolfz function now because the function I need to fit is not actually quite a Voight profile. There are actually two different Lorentzians put together. Anyway, to get my program started I tried writing my own regular voight profile from scratch. For all my test parameters, it produces the exact same output as the wolfz algorithm. However when I try to fit it to a data set, unlike the wolfz algorithm it gives me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_two.py", line 99, in <module>
    output =  opt.curve_fit(TWO_VOIGHT,x_arr,y_arr, guess)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 581, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 371, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 20, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 447, in _general_function
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
  File "test_two.py", line 46, in TWO_VOIGHT
    output = integrate.quad(lambda x: VOIGHT_INTEGRAND(x,det,shift,alpha,gamma_a),-np.inf,0.0)[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 311, in quad
    points)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 378, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
quadpack.error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

Here is my code...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import os
import re
import math
from scipy import integrate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import wofz

def VOIGHT_INTEGRAND(x,x_func,x0,alpha,gamma_a):

    output = np.exp(-alpha*((x-x0)**2.0))
    output = ((alpha/pi)**(1.0/2.0))*output
    output = output*(gamma_a/(2.0*pi))
    output = output/(((x-x_func)**(2.0)) + ((gamma_a/2.0)**2.0))

    return output

def TWO_VOIGHT(det,gamma_a,shift,scale):

    sigma = SIGMA_CALC(1.3e-6, (88.0 * 1.67e-27),4.34829121312334e14*2.0*pi)
    sigma =  sigma/gamma
    alpha = 1.0/(2.0*sigma*sigma)
    output = integrate.quad(lambda x: VOIGHT_INTEGRAND(x,det,shift,alpha,gamma_a),-np.inf,np.inf)[0]
    output = output*scale

    return output 


def SIGMA_CALC(temp,mass, hertz):

    sigma = math.sqrt((hertz**2.0) * (1.381e-23) * temp / (mass * (3.0e8 * 3.0e8)))
    return sigma


f = open('out_gauss_1.0E+17_N_400.out','r')


x_arr = []
y_arr = []
for line in f:
    line_arr = line.split()
    x_arr.append(float(line_arr[0]))
    y_arr.append(float(line_arr[1]))
guess  = np.array([1.0,0.0,1.0])    

output =  opt.curve_fit(TWO_VOIGHT,x_arr,y_arr, guess)

print 'Gamma 1:', output[0][0]/width, n_atoms
print 'Gamma 2:', output[0][1]/width
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Do you guys have any ideas?

The contents of the file I open are:

```
-6.4 0.237952863717 
-6.2 0.268912617983 
-6.0 0.305446644483 
-5.8 0.3485094196 
-5.6 0.398708815217 
-5.4 0.456942840517 
-5.2 0.524574736517 
-5.0 0.602806918033 
-4.8 0.692499762417 
-4.6 0.794458526383 
-4.4 0.909341570333 
-4.2 1.03784998038 
-4.0 1.18085462442 
-3.8 1.33867094077 
-3.6 1.51124577498 
-3.4 1.69824987307 
-3.2 1.8986205928 
-3.0 2.11082341933 
-2.8 2.33307233833 
-2.6 2.5631992475 
-2.4 2.79829104117 
-2.2 3.0351678375 
-2.0 3.2708957095 
-1.8 3.50152844917 
-1.6 3.72206345267 
-1.4 3.928262486 
-1.2 4.11657091433 
-1.0 4.2838813515 
-0.8 4.426546224 
-0.6 4.54028968367 
-0.4 4.62285975717 
-0.2 4.67327511933 
0.0 4.690377612 
0.2 4.673365306 
0.4 4.622312377 
0.6 4.5382663485 
0.8 4.42294278633 
1.0 4.2796806435 
1.2 4.11257992183 
1.4 3.92422074583 
1.6 3.71751059817 
1.8 3.49728613283 
2.0 3.267883908 
2.2 3.03266881417 
2.4 2.79548030417 
2.6 2.56023351717 
2.8 2.33020427217 
3.0 2.10810391283 
3.2 1.89634314437 
3.4 1.69664525222 
3.6 1.50996288777 
3.8 1.3371250582 
4.0 1.17885436362 
4.2 1.03533114692 
4.4 0.906425218067 
4.6 0.7918292208 
4.8 0.690636432067 
5.0 0.6017171318 
5.2 0.524059884217 
5.4 0.456797620467 
5.6 0.398844547883 
5.8 0.348953529967 
6.0 0.306220038467 
6.2 0.269773789833
```

The function seems to return a scalar. I checked using this:

```
x_arr = np.linspace(-6,6,100)
y1_arr = []
y2_arr = []

for x in x_arr:
    y1_arr.append(TWO_VOIGHT(x,1.0,0.0,1.0))
    print TWO_VOIGHT(x,1.0,0.0,1.0)
```

Comment: Your function is probably not returning a scalar.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22730434/4080476  I couldn't get your code to work as is, you need to supply the correct imports and xArr and yArr in order to test reproduce this.

Comment: It would help if you could edit the code in the question to be a self-contained, runnable example that reproduces the problem.  Currently, you don't have any imports in that code, and you define `x_arr` and `y_arr` but use `xArr` and `yArr`.  A runnable example would greatly improve the chances that someone will correctly identify the problem.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't realize I had two copies of the code open at once. I fixed it I think.

Comment: This is probably not the main problem, but in the function `TWO_VOIGHT`, you have the line `sigma =  sigma/gamma`, but `gamma` is not defined.  Presumably this should be `gamma_a`.